# Visual studio with unity3D wont work like it used to be

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I've searched the internet for a week i couldn't find any resolution when i upgraded to unity 5.3.2 or 5.3.3 i cant remember it just break my visual studio even when i upgrade to unity 5.4 beta still doesnt work any way to fix thiS? im desperate and in need to use visual studio because its easier and user-friendly code editor

Theres no color(no intelli-sense) and when i tried to use unity3d variable like transform.rotatetoward it doesnt show anything

[image]

And over here it says that i enabled my visual studio tools

[image]

i tried countless way to do this fix around the internet

- by reinstalling unity3d and visual studio
- deleting all the .sln, .csproject, vscode folder so unity will generate new one
- i tried using a plugin to connect unity with visual studio

it just doesnt work anymore

**MY VISUAL STUDIO INFO**

> **Microsoft visual studio community 2015** version
>   14.0.23107.0 D14REL
>
> ***Installed products***
>
> **Visual basic 2015** 00322-20000-00000-AA455
>
> **Visual c# 2015** 00322-20000-00000-AA455
>
> **Visual C++ 2015** 00322-20000-00000-AA455
>
> **Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package** 1.0
>
> **Common Azure Tools** 1.5
>
> **GenerateUnitTest** 1.0
>
> **Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools** 1.4
>
> **NuGet Packkage Manager** 3.0.0
>
> **PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer** 1.2
>
> ***Product Details:***
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Comment: do receving a dialogue box when opening the VS?

Comment: Theres no receiveing of any dialog it just shows the code @MohammadFaizanKhan

http://imgur.com/bFWItnT (except this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a **bug** on some operating systems because the-same thing happened to me last week. This maybe due to Windows auto update that broke something. The current workaround is to **not** open your C# file from unity.

Instead, go to **Assets**->**Show in Explorer** then open the name of the project with the **.sln** extension.

Then to open your C# file in visual studio,  there is a **Window** on the right side of **Visual Studio**. Under it, select a tab called **Solution Explorer**. There you can open your C# file.

Everything will be back to normal and it wont open the C# file as **Miscellaneous** file. This is how you should be opening your files from **Visual Studio** until Unity fixes this bug.

Comment: I tried open my c# project with **(game name).sln** and it still register my c# project as ***misc*** file

Comment: I have your problem and I use visual studio 2013 but the problem started after windows update. this fixed it for me.

Comment: You opened the C# file from visual studio instead of double-clicking it in Unity?

Comment: Wait no i didnt read the edited version, i always open my c# in unity where can i find this  "there is a Window on the right side of Visual Studio. Under it, select a tab called Solution Explorer" which window?

is it this one? http://imgur.com/E2hucwj
if its this one therefor there is no solution explorer

Comment: That window is missing from your picture. Don't open from Unity. Read my answer again. Got to **View->Solution Explorer** in visual studio if it missing. You are using VS 2015 so I don't know if it will be there but try going to **View->Solution Explorer** and that window will come up on the right.

Comment: It actually works, thanks alot this is what i have been searching for ages, thanks alot, you are a life saver :) kudos for you :)

Comment: No problem. I was stuck on that too but this is the solution for now.

Comment: em it just worked, and after i restart my pc it did the same as the last time it doesnt work again great.. emm now what? .-.
sorry for the "more" questions

http://imgur.com/ytsk2w9

i did what you said **Assets --> Show in explorer --> Final dawn.sln** for some reason now it wont work no more :(

Comment: lol why would you even re-start your computer? :)

Comment: Close visual studio. Go to Unity Editor then go to **Assets->Re-import All** then follow my instruction over again. Open the sln file and open the C# file from Visual Studio. If that fails, Uninstall Unity, Uninstall Visual Studio then restart computer. Don't skip the re-start step. Install Unity and Visual Studio again and then follow my answer again. That should solve your problem again....